# Dynamic LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, .net-4.5

I am trying to query database using EF and LINQ. I have multiple queries to filter data based on user permissions with in the application.

```
from p in db.EmployeeDetails
join i in db.EmployeeDept on p.DeptId equals i.DeptId into inst
from i in inst.DefaultIfEmpty()
join s in db.Employee on p.EmpId equals s.EmpId into manager
from s in manager.DefaultIfEmpty()
join e in db.EmpStatus on p.EnrollmentStatusID equals e.StatusID into estatus
from e in estatus.DefaultIfEmpty()
where p.SomeId== id && (p.IsActive == true || p.SomeStatus == null)
select new EmployeeBase
{
  //select list common to all queries. 
};
```

This is the example of a base query. To this I need to add one more where clauses if user belongs to a specific role and a new table if user belongs to some other role. I was able to do this with five different queries with if...else condition checks. But a new requirement brings more conditions and more tables and more where clauses to be added which makes the code so repetitive that turns out to be a nightmare for maintenance .

I tried PredicateBuilder but I am not sure how can I apply PredicateBuilder with multiple entities and outer join's.

I found about Dynamic LINQ Library from ScottGu's block but I am not sure if it has a .Net 4.5 version and is helpful in this case.

Is there a way that I can construct the query dynamically so that I don't need to change every query when there is a small change in the requirement.

Comment: Select into an `IQueryable<EmployeeBase>` variable first, and construct your `where` clauses on that.  Alternatively, dynamically construct a raw SQL query and execute it against EF using DBRawSqlQuery.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear as to exactly what you need to change. If all you need is more `where` clauses, you can always just chain more `.Where` clauses on. If it's more fundamental then it's a little trickier, but if the type you eventually select is the same in the end, it might be still doable. Some better (and simpler) examples to illustrate what you are trying to do might help.

Comment: @MattBurland I need to add more entities also to the base query as either inner join or outer join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public IQueryable<EmployeeBase> Employees() {
    return (

    from p in db.EmployeeDetails
    join i in db.EmployeeDept on p.DeptId equals i.DeptId into inst
    from i in inst.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join s in db.Employee on p.EmpId equals s.EmpId into manager
    from s in manager.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join e in db.EmpStatus on p.EnrollmentStatusID equals e.StatusID into estatus
    from e in estatus.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where p.SomeId== id && (p.IsActive == true || p.SomeStatus == null)
    select new EmployeeBase
    {
      //select list common to all queries. 
    });
}
```

...

```
var awesomeEmployee=Employees().Single(x=>x.name=="Me");
var listToFire=Employees().OrderByDescending(x=>x.Salary).Take(3);
var listToPromote=Employees().OrderByDescending(x=>x.Performance).Take(1);
```

Although, I'd recommend reusing the EF objects, and making sure you have navigation properties set up correctly.  From your code, it looks like you aren't using them at all -- which leads you to the mess you have.  You really should just have something like these extension methods:

```
public static IQueryable<EmployeeDetails> IsActive(this IQueryable<EmployeeDetails> eb) {
    return eb.Where(p=>p.IsActive == true || p.SomeStatus == null);
}
```

Then you can access your data like:

```
var employee=db.EmployeeDetails
  .IsActive()
  .Include(x=>x.Manager);

foreach(var e in employee) { 
  Console.Writeline("{0}'s manager is {1}",
    e.name,
    e.Manager.name);
}
```